# HP laptop boot loop & black screen

Tags: windows, boot, post

After loading a driver for an external usb wifi adapter, this laptop is having issues booting.

Symptoms are:

```
Boots up but loops after 15 seconds or so, don't know if it is actually posting
Black screen (as in screen does not turn on at all)
```

Things tried:

```
Pulled all memory, all peripherals and reset CMOS battery. Then inserted 1 memory stick with no changes.
Pulled battery, no changes.
```

Any ideas of what to try next?

Comment: Dose an external monitor work?

Comment: Just tried one, no it doesn't.

Comment: Tap F8 at boot, you will get a boot menu to try Safe Mode and various Recovery options.  Try those, Report back.

Comment: How would I do that when as mentioned above that my screen is black?

Comment: Use a bright flashlight on the screen, do you see anything while booting?, if you do see the post screen using the flashlight your backlight or inverter has failed (LCD screen only).

Comment: No beeping? Black screen is a good symptom of BGA failure due to overheating.. But that comes with beeps and don't recall it loop-rebooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not a driver problem as bootup doesn't involve drivers.  If the machine does not POST, pull the hard drive and see if it POSTs.  If it doesn't its time to call HP.  If it does boot into cmos reset to defaults, and try again.